# Convert any datetime format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have the following two different formats of dates as shown below:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(50) = '2019-11-06 00:00:00'
DECLARE @A1 VARCHAR(50) = '06-11-2019 00:00:00'
```

I need to write a **single** conversion statement which convert any of above format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss`.

Tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@A) AS A, CONVERT(DATETIME,@A1) AS A1
```

Getting:

```
A                           A1
---------------------------------------------------------
2019-11-06 00:00:00.000     2019-06-11 00:00:00.000
```

Expected:

```
A                           A1
---------------------------------------------------------
2019-11-06 00:00:00.000     2019-11-06 00:00:00.000
```

I don't want to write two different convertion statement because I never know which input date is of which format.

Comment: A `DATETIME` doesn't have a format. and what you have is a formatted string not a `DATETIME`

Comment: So, who the engine is suppose to know which variant is correct? If these are parameters, ensure that when the routine is called, the same format is passed. If this is legacy data - create datetime column and fix the data by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case to check if you have the first or the second format, and then call the convert function providing their exact format (105 for dd-mm-yyy and 120 for yyyy-mm-dd).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
select case when substring(@A, 3, 1) = '-' then convert(datetime, @A, 105) 
            else convert(datetime, @A, 120) 
       end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,@A), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss')
```

Comment: mind the "mm" in the date probably should be "MM". lowercase is minutes uppercase is month

Answer (score 0):

You can check the date formatting. Then apply the desired conversion.

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(50) = '2019-11-06 00:00:00'
DECLARE @A1 VARCHAR(50) = '06-11-2019 00:00:00'


select case when convert(varchar, @A, 105) = @A then convert(datetime, @A, 120)  else convert(datetime, @A, 120)  end;
select case when convert(varchar, @A1, 105) = @A1 then convert(datetime, @A1, 105)  else convert(datetime, @A1, 105)  end;
```